# Update config injection to take the name of a config file at run-time rather than it being hardcoded

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, webpack

I am using wbepack and trying to be more dynamic with the configs in my when building my application. It is a `create-react-app` project which has been ejected.

For example if I want to make a local build in my `package.json` file I have the following.

`"build:local": "APPLICATION_ENV=local npm run build",`

I would like to have a custom build where I can pass in a json file which it would then use that config.

`"custom": "APPLICATION_ENV=custom CUSTOM_ENV=test.json  npm run build",`

I think it would be ok to get this to work, however is there anyway I can make the name of the json file dynamic enabling me to decide which json file to use as opposed to having to hard code it in my `package.json`.

in my head something like this:

`npm run build:custom CUSTOM_CONFIG=hulkhogan.json`

Does anyone have any idea how to approach this? Maybe something like [this](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3494).

Comment: Why do you want to pass config inside webpack config?

Comment: I want to be able to update config injection to take the name of a config file at run-time rather than it being hardcoded, to allow for personalised configuration

Answer (score 2):

Check out https://www.npmjs.com/package/better-npm-run might be useful for this.